# Is there support for subplots in highcharts as in plotly?

Tags: highcharts, plotly.js

Looking for support for subplots in Highcharts

https://plot.ly/javascript/subplots/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Highcharts you can create multiple charts or multiple axes:

```
series: [{
    data: [...]
}, {
    data: [...],
    yAxis: 1,
    xAxis: 1
}],

xAxis: [{
    left: '0%',
    width: '40%',
    offset: 0
}, {
    left: '60%',
    width: '40%',
    offset: 0
}],
yAxis: [{
    left: '0%',
    width: '40%',
    offset: 0
}, {
    left: '60%',
    width: '40%',
    offset: 0
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8Lvmq6sh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.xAxis

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek, any support for titles?

Comment: Hi @Erez, You can use `axis.title` property: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6naz0ugj/